# lambda check for null and then set to 0

Tags: c#, linq

In this example I have a nullable int and in the lambda I want to set it to 0 and then do a compare. If it `null` I want to set it to `0` and then campare it to  `<= 1`. How can HasValue in the lambda where condition ?

```
var exchangeAttemptsList = ExchangeRequestList
                          .Where( x => x.ExchangeAttempts.HasValue
                            ? x.ExchangeAttempts.Value
                            : 1 <= 1
                          )
                          .ToList()
                          ;
```

Sample

https://dotnetfiddle.net/f5BD4n

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `Where(x => (x.ExchangeAttempts ?? 0) <= 1)`?

Comment: Can I use HasValue ? in the where condition of a lambda?

Comment: It's easier if you don't

Comment: Yes, you just need to wrap it in parentheses.  Jeroen's comment is even better.  Please edit your question to include the error message.

Comment: You probably need `Where(x => x.ExchangeAttempts.HasValue ? x.ExchangeAttempts.Value <= 1 : true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression makes no sense (and doesn't compile):

```
x => x.ExchangeAttempts.HasValue
   ? x.ExchangeAttempts.Value
   : 1 <= 1
```

That is the exact equivalent (assuming that `ExchangeAttempts` is an `int?` of:

```
int lambda( x MyClass )
{
  int result;

  if ( x.ExchangeAttempts.HasValue )
  {
    result = x.ExchangeAttempts.Value ;
  }
  else
  {
    result = 1 <= 1 ; 
  }
  return result;
}
```

It fails to compile because the expression `1 <= 1` evaluates to `true`.

If what you want to do is assign a default value of `1` if `ExchangeAttempts` is `null`, just say:

```
x => (x.ExchangeAttempts ?? 1) <= 1
```

It's shorter and more concise, and better expresses your intent.

Or, better yet:

```
x => x.ExchangeAttempts == null || x.ExchangeAttempts <= 1
```

Logical expressions short circuit, so the alternative is only ever tried if the first test fails, so the above returns `true` when either

- `x.ExchangeAttempts` has no value, or
- `x.ExchangeAttempts` has a value less than or equal to 1

And returns `false` when

- `x.ExchangeAttempts` has a value and that value is > 1.